# Can I cheat and use static fields instead of intent in this case?

Tags: java, android

What I hope to accomplish:

Build one activity.

Build one service to handle a small data collection (estimated size:<=5k bytes)

Activity communicates with service on a regular basis.

I've read several posts and decided it's best for me to send the updated data (an object) from activity to service using Intent.putextra().

However the whole thing seems to be a huge hassle, I have to modify some of my code and according to one Android Developer from google, I can straight up use static fields, which as I was told by many, is a really bad practice, but will make my job much easier. To use intent, I have to deal with something called "serializing" and worse, I might have to implement yet another interface, on top of my already implemented comparable interface.

Although all of the posts I've read are about activity communicating with another activity, I think everything should hold true regarding activity vs service situation.

Only the app itself or the system has the power to destroy this service. Can I cheat? I mean if a google employee said it's OK, may be the whole "Thou shall not use static fields" thing is like the "better not use *goto* in your code" thing - kind of... exaggerated?

Comment: Ask yourself if you want to spend some extra time writing proper code, or if you want to write a quick dirty fix that might cause bugs some day. Writing proper code always takes more time initially, but it will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Static members break features like instant run. But there are a number of reasons why you should avoid using them.

Comment: Intent it is. Why-ever there is a static field in the first place.